# How to export bbPress (forums, topics, replies) and all users?

Tags: users, bbpress

I've searched a little and I could not find a straight working answer.
I want to export all users and their bbPress(2.1.2) forums, topics and replies to another fresh WordPress installation?

If anyone has a suggestion.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will have to take the backup from database.
If you need bbPress data only, you can only dump this tables from your WordPress installation:

```
bb_forums
bb_meta 
bb_posts 
bb_tagged 
bb_tags 
bb_terms 
bb_term_relationships 
bb_term_taxonomy 
bb_topics 
bb_topicmeta 
bb_users 
bb_usermeta
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [small plugin](https://github.com/pippinsplugins/bbPress-Export-and-Import) that does it for you.

You have to do it one forum at a time, but it will handle all forums, topics, replies, and users.

Comment: This plugin is not maintained anymore

Answer (score 0):

Export the data with a database manager. The native WordPress exporter is written just for simple blogs. It will miss data like custom tables or users without posts.